# Can't use S3 backend with Terraform - missing credentials

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the most pedestrian of a Terraform sample:

```
#  Configure AWS provider
provider "aws" {
    region     = "us-east-1"
    access_key = "xxxxxxxxx"
    secret_key = "yyyyyyyyyyy"
}

#  Terraform configuration
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "terraform.example.com"
    key    = "85/182/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

When I run terraform init I receive the following (traced) response:

```
2018/08/14 14:19:13 [INFO] Terraform version: 0.11.7  41e50bd32a8825a84535e353c3674af8ce799161
2018/08/14 14:19:13 [INFO] Go runtime version: go1.10.1
2018/08/14 14:19:13 [INFO] CLI args: []string{"C:\\cygwin64\\usr\\local\\bin\\terraform.exe", "init"}
2018/08/14 14:19:13 [DEBUG] Attempting to open CLI config file: C:\Users\judall\AppData\Roaming\terraform.rc
2018/08/14 14:19:13 [DEBUG] File doesn't exist, but doesn't need to. Ignoring.
2018/08/14 14:19:13 [INFO] CLI command args: []string{"init"}
2018/08/14 14:19:13 [DEBUG] command: loading backend config file: C:\cygwin64\home\judall\t2

2018/08/14 14:19:13 [DEBUG] command: no data state file found for backend config
Initializing the backend...
2018/08/14 14:19:13 [DEBUG] New state was assigned lineage "5113646b-318f-9612-5057-bc4803292c3a"
2018/08/14 14:19:13 [INFO] Building AWS region structure
2018/08/14 14:19:13 [INFO] Building AWS auth structure
2018/08/14 14:19:13 [INFO] Setting AWS metadata API timeout to 100ms
2018/08/14 14:19:13 [INFO] Ignoring AWS metadata API endpoint at default location as it doesn't return any instance-id

2018/08/14 14:19:13 [DEBUG] plugin: waiting for all plugin processes to complete...
Error configuring the backend "s3": No valid credential sources found for AWS Provider.
  Please see https://terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html for more information on
  providing credentials for the AWS Provider

Please update the configuration in your Terraform files to fix this error
then run this command again.
```

I've been googling for hours on this.  I've tried to use the 'profile' property - which yields slightly different trace logs, but the same end result.  I've tried setting the AWS_ environment variables - with the same result.

I'm running terraform version 0.11.7.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12):

The `provider` configuration is independent from your `backend` configuration.

The credentials, you have configured in the `provider` block, are used to create your AWS related resources. For accessing S3 bucket as a storage for your remote state, you also need to provide credentials. This can be the same like in the config for your `provider` or can be completely different (with permissions only on this specific bucket for security reasons).

You can fix it by adding the credentials in the `backend` block:

```
#  Terraform configuration
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket     = "terraform.example.com"
    key        = "85/182/terraform.tfstate"
    region     = "us-east-1"
    access_key = "xxxxxxxxx"
    secret_key = "yyyyyyyyyyy"
  }
}
```

Or you can create an AWS (default) profile in your home directory ([Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-config-files.html)) and remove your credentials in your terraform code (preferred option, when you store your config in a version control system).

Comment: Many thanks!  I did somewhat surmise this.  However, it was obscured by the fact that having added that information, I had to then add the -reconfigure option to my init command.  Just a further FYI for folks.  Again - thanks for your response

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by @JimUdall in the comment, if you are re-running init on an updated backend configuration, you need to use `-reconfigure` for the updated config to apply the changed configuration.

```
terraform init -reconfigure
```