# Using AWS Terraform How to enable s3 backend authentication with assumed role MFA credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, multi-factor-authentication

I provision AWS resources using Terraform using a python script that call terraform via shell

```
os.system('terraform apply')
```

The only way I found to enable terraform authentication, after enabling MFA and assuming a role, is to publish these environment variables:

```
os.system('export ASSUMED_ROLE="<>:botocore-session-123";
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="vfdgdsfg";
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="fgbdzf";
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="fsrfserfgs";
export AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN="fsrfserfgs"; terraform apply')
```

This worked OK until I configured s3 as backend, terraform action is performed but before the state can be stored in the bucket I get the standard (very confusing) exception:

```
Error: error configuring S3 Backend: Error creating AWS session: AssumeRoleTokenProviderNotSetError: assume role with MFA enabled, but AssumeRoleTokenProvider session option not set.
```

I read this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51946463/1447071) explaining that for security and other reasons backend configuration is separate.

Since I don't want to add actual secret keys to source code (as suggested by the post) I tried adding a reference to the profile and when it failed I added the actual keys just to see if it would work, which it didn't.

My working theory is that behind the scenes terraform starts another process which doesn't access or inherit the credential e environment variables.

How do I use s3 backend, with an MFA assumed role?

Comment: Is this also causing issues during `init`?

Comment: @MattSchuchard no

Answer (score 0):

One must point the backend to the desired profile. In my case the same profile used for the provisioning itself.

Here is a minimal POC

```
terraform {

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }

  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "unique-terraform-state-dev"
    key    = "test"
    region = "us-east-2"

    profile = "the_role_assumed_in_aws_credentials"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  version = "~> 3.0"
  region  = var.region
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket" {

  bucket = var.bucket_name
}
```

I'm reminding that it's run by shell which has these environment variables:

```
os.system('export ASSUMED_ROLE="<>:botocore-session-123";
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="vfdgdsfg";
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="fgbdzf";
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="fsrfserfgs";
export AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN="fsrfserfgs"; terraform apply')
```